# What scenarios is the rpmspec `Requires` directive enforced?

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

Let's say I have `mog.rpm` with an rpmspec that defines the following `Requires` direction:

```
Requires: kupo >= 2.0
```

I know the `Requires` is enforced on rpm installation/upgrade.  Is it enforced at any other time?  For example, if `kupo v2.0` has some regression and I downgrade it to `kupo v1.9`, will the `Requires` directive in `mog.rpm` prevent the downgrade?  Or is that only enforced when changes (i.e. installation/upgrade/downgrade) are being made to `mog.rpm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is enforced all the time.